Телеграм-бот, удаление сообщений и проверка онлайн-кнопок
Вопрос первый: подскажите, а реально как-нибудь удалить сообщение бота в «Телеграме» для определённых людей? Использую библиотеку telebot. Есть необходимость сделать, чтобы бот удалял сообщения практически для всех пользователей, кроме того пользователя, который вводил команду.
Вопрос второй: как сделать всё на той же библиотеке telebot проверку, кто нажал на инлай кнопку с ссылкой. А именно, бот отправляет инлайн кнопку, на которой ссылка, которая перебрасывает пользователя в другую группу, как сделать, чтобы по этой ссылке мог перейти только тот пользователь, который вызвал эту кнопку?
Сразу извиняюсь за тупые вопросы, сама понимаю, что сделать это вряд ли реально, но, может, есть выход из этих ситуаций.

Первое: удалить одно сообщение в группе для определённых пользователей невозможно, вместо этого можно просто отправить нужному пользователю личное сообщение или всплывающее уведомление
Второе: контролировать кто нажал инлайн кнопку с ссылкой невозможно, легче опять таки просто отправить личное сообщение с ссылкой
